# Visualizing broad Tikz tree graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, tikz-qtree

Modules of software I created produce Tikz QTree diagrams for visualisation. The problem is that some trees grow quite broad...

[image]

Even when I try to massively shrink them by Tikz settings, I cannot fit them on the page. I use the following, which has no effect:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=1mm/#1}]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\tiny]
  \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=2mm]
  \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=2mm]
  \tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=2mm]
```

Is there a way to further size them down or/ and another way to visualize Tikz output (like an applet or something?).

Comment: Perhaps exporting to TikZ is not your best option for displaying these kinds of graphs. In my experience the node placement algorithms are not that great. I have had good experiences with [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) in the past for visualizing very large graphs. If you are looking at applets then I assume you are not interested in printing and perhaps just increasing the size of the page is a possibility as well.

Comment: You should consider rotating the graph by -90 degress. I would rather use a non-tikz solution such as `dirtree`, which provides more like a directory structure.

Comment: `tikz-qtree` doesn't use the levels of the standard `tikz` trees so setting the level distances like you have has no effect. You could try adding `[grow'=right]` to the `tikzpicture` and have the trees displayed vertically.

Comment: Wouldn't just enclosing the `tikzpicture` into `\resizebox{\textwidth}` or suchlike solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible solutions, as pointed out in comments. The simplest would be to use `\resizebox{\textwidth}` around the entire tree to resize it to the current width. Most likely, that would need to be done using a landscape page to give you more space to use. However, the underlying problem is that a tree representation is just not a good one for this data: you really need to rethink the appearance, and that is not a TeX issue!